# Best way to add a shadow and colored border to ClipRRect using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple `ClipRRect` widget as the below one:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          child: GridTile(
        child: Image.network(
          imageUrl,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        footer: GridTileBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          title: Text(
            title,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            onPressed: () {},
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried to add a shadow by wrapping this widget with another `Card` widget to add a shadow with an `elevation` as the below code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        elevation: 5,
          child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: GridTile(
          child: Image.network(
            imageUrl,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          footer: GridTileBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            title: Text(
              title,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

but I think it's not logical at all because it shows the grid item a bit smaller, and also I need add a `border` in this grid..

I hope this would be clear enough..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can create your widget to take in a shadow and border colors as follows
since ClipRRect cant take in shadow or border color we use a container

clipRRect constructor

```
ClipRRect({Key key, BorderRadius borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero, CustomClipper<RRect> clipper, Clip clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, Widget child})
```

.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      child: Card(
        elevation: 4.0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
            side: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.green)),
        child: Center(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.movie,
            size: 150.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.white54,
            blurRadius: 5.0,
            offset: Offset(0, 10),
            spreadRadius: 0.5,
          ),
        ],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: result]

Comment: thanks for your support , but I can't create shadow and border directly to `ClipRRect ` right?, I think in your example you have just removed the `ClipRRect ` as-well

Comment: yes  ` ClipRRect({Key key, BorderRadius borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero, CustomClipper<RRect> clipper, Clip clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, Widget child}) `  from its constructors it doesnt support that

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution which worked for me.

```
Container(
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    child: SizedBox(
      child: ImageWidget(imageUrl),
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    ),
  ),
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    color: Colors.white,
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.15),
        blurRadius: 8,
        spreadRadius: 6,
        offset: const Offset(0, 0),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it like below

```
       Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
            Container(
              width: DeviceUtils.getScaledHeight(context, 0.072),
              height: DeviceUtils.getScaledHeight(context, 0.072),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.green),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.white54,
                    blurRadius: 5.0,
                    offset: Offset(0, 10),
                    spreadRadius: 0.5,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              child: ImageFromURL(
                  url: "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/63/81/a7/6381a77565b51a541d0d85cb145e7d94.jpg",
                  width: DeviceUtils.getScaledHeight(context, 0.07),
                  height: DeviceUtils.getScaledHeight(context, 0.07)),
            ),
          ])
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Use this Code : -

```
Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 140,
                      height: 140,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: greyColor,
                          blurRadius: 1.0,
                          spreadRadius: 0.0,
                          offset: Offset(
                              1.0, 1.0), // shadow direction: bottom right
                        )
                      ], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(70)),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        child: getImageWidget(imagePath),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(70),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 108, top: 108),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/group.png",
                          width: 32,
                          height: 32,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: (){
                        pickImage();
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
```